# Retrieve next row data every 5 mins

Tags: javascript, php

I have rows of data in my database table,
How to display

- First; row ID 1,
- after 5 mins row ID 2,
- after 5 mins row ID 3

and so on, Automatically.

The webpage will auto retrieve next row every 5 mins and only display that row.
kinda like refreshing every 5 mins but displaying next row not the latest one.

below is my code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #main {
                margin:5% 15% 10% 15%;
                background:url(viewBG.png);
                width:70%;
                height:80%;
            }
            p {
                padding:20% 20% 20% 20%;
                color:white;
                font-family: Honey Script;
                font-size:30pt;
            }
            body {
                background-color: skyblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            //connection to 
            require 'config.php';

            $conn = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

            // Create connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            //$sql = "SELECT * FROM `demo` ORDER BY `ID` DESC ";
            $sql = "SELECT Comment FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<div id="main">';
                    echo '  <p>"'.$row["Comment"].'"</p>';
                    echo "</div>";
                }

            } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
        $conn->close();        
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is content replaced by the new one?  or appended to the old content?

Comment: Did you run it? What happened with this code? What result did you get?

Comment: Just a suggestion, add a new field to the table like 'show_status' with default value 0.Update its value to one each time you one row.
then modify the query as :SELECT Comment FROM demo Where  show_status = 0 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: You will either need to fetch all rows, hide them, and rotate through each. Or fetch only one row, and then use ajax to fetch the next. Either one requires some javascript, which you have not even attempted before asking here. So take some time try something, and then come back if you need help.

Comment: @sean so how is that written?

Comment: @mdamia My database will constantly receive inputs from a form.

Comment: @Alfabravo now it just shows the biggest row data with me reloading the page.

Comment: I need it to auto reload like transit from row one to row 2 and so on.

Comment: @ChristopheHsu, Ajax is the way to go

Comment: @ChristopheHsu. You will need to build some logic to accomplish what you want. Always send the row id being displayed, increment by 1 to get the next row. Check if it's the last row in the table, if so return the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to combine javascript in your solution. Make your php script to echo a form with a parameter with the next row to retrieve, lets say in php this :

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST["next_row"])) { 
            $myrow = $_REQUEST["next_row"]; 
        } else {
            $myrow = 0;
        }

        echo '<form id=myform> <input type=hidden name="next_row" value="'.($myrow * 1 + 1).'"> </form>';
        //connection to 
        require 'config.php';

        $conn = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

        // Create connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM `demo` ORDER BY `ID` DESC ";
        $sql = "SELECT Comment FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET ". $myrow;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<div id="main">';
                echo '  <p>"'.$row["Comment"].'"</p>';
                echo "</div>";
            }

        } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
    $conn->close();        
    ?>
```

Ok now on Javascript at the end of the page the following code (be sure to include jquery.js):

setTimeout(function(){ $('#myform').submit(); }, 300000);

Comment: this code only reloads and displays the latest. not the next row

Comment: you can do whatever you want, that case you may want instead of submitting you may want to work with ajax, or fade in with javascript too when loading the page and fadeout inside the settimeout before submitting. I suggest having a white or black overlay layer for this.

Comment: oh yes, the color is just for trial, ill change it once ready.   So the fadein and out timer is before the setTimeout(function(){ $('#myform').submit(); }, 300000);?

Comment: you need to remove the -1 from the condition, i am sorry.

Comment: The code to fadeout would be inside the time out: setTimeout(function(){ function_to_fadeout(); $('#myform').submit(); }, 300000);

Comment: The code to fadein would be executed as you load the page. before even setting the timeout

Comment: could you advice me how is typed, my apologise. I did this    '<script>
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                fadeOut("slow");
                $('#myform').submit();
                fadeIn("slow");
            },30000);
        </script>'

Comment: ok. you should fadein outside the timeout  '<script> fadeIn("slow"); setTimeout(function(){ fadeOut("slow"); $('#myform').submit(); },300000); </script>'

Comment: you will have to work around the javascript execution, the basic idea was already ok, check fadeout and fadein, try removing them to see which is making the function fail. It is almost 2 clock in us, i am sleepy :-(

Comment: sorry to trouble you, because of the addition, this code tries to receive data on rows that do not exist. Can we retrieve the biggest row ID? so + 1 but if < then row ID then continue to display biggest row ID input

Comment: hey the solution is to first count the amount of rows in the query and compare it with the requested amount, if the requested row is greater than the amount of rows in the query, then dont increase the the offset variable and make sure javascript knows there is no new row so you dont update the page for no reason. Important. Javascript will continue looking in case a new row appears in the database.

Comment: Please help, what is the code to get the number of rows? I can't personally count the amount of rows. The number will keep changing. we need to do a condition, if example 5 is the biggest row; stay at row 5 else if new row, display new row. How is that written? :)